# How to properly setup vsock on a buildroot guest?

Tags: qemu, buildroot

Currently trying out `vsock` for host-guest communication; but when I test out the connection with `ncat`,

- `Ncat: Connection timed out` pops out if the guest is listening, and the host tries to connect to the guest with `<ncat -v --vsock <guest cid> <port>`
- `Ncat: Connection reset by peer` pops out if the host is listening, and the guest tries to connect with `ncat -v --vsock 2 <port>`

The host system is Ubuntu 22.04 with the 6.2.0 kernel, and the guest was built by buildroot, having the 6.2 kernel, and `VIRTIO_VSOCKET=m` and `VHOST_VSOCK=m` were set.

In the guest machine, before `ncat`, `modprobe vsock` and `modprobe vhost-vsock` were also performed in advance; the following is the result of `lsmod` on the guest machine:

```
# lsmod | grep vsock
vhost_vsock            20480  0 
vmw_vsock_virtio_transport_common    28672  1 vhost_vsock
vhost                  36864  1 vhost_vsock
vsock                  49152  2 vhost_vsock,vmw_vsock_virtio_transport_common
```

And this is how I started the virtual machine:

```bash
sudo build/qemu/x86_64-softmmu/qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm \
    -M pc \
    -kernel ./build/buildroot/images/bzImage \
    -drive file=./build/buildroot/images/rootfs.ext2,if=virtio,format=raw \
    -append "root=/dev/vda console=ttyS0" \
    -net nic,model=virtio -net user \
    -virtfs local,path=./share,mount_tag=share,security_model=mapped-xattr \
    -device vhost-vsock-pci,guest-cid=123 \
    -nographic
```

What am I doing wrong, and what should I do to fix it? Any help would be appreciated, and thanks in advance.